# looking for a superviser for my code

Tags: javascript, feedback

I'm on the learning stage, and i need some feedback for the code I've write. Do you have any idea about how can I get another pair of eyes with a smarter brain to look over my code?

ps: It is about a code written in js.

Comment: Feel free to post a link to some code. I might have a look at it if it doesn't burn my eyes. Also try the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript)

Comment: @Raynos: ty for your offer. Here is my code: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/466/need-a-feedback-on-my-javascript-code-and-app-implementation-idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a StackExchange site for that: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: that's cool and a great idea, but codereview is new and I'm curious how the things were before stackexchange

Answer (score 2):

If you are learning Javascript make sure you pass your code threw JSLint (jslint.com) it will
find a lot of the stupid errors people tend to make.

Comment: JSLint will hurt your feelings!

Comment: yes it will, but it will cause you to learn!